# Swift Perform Segue One Step Behind

Tags: swift, xcode, segue

I am trying to create a simple meditation app where when I click a button with time - it takes me to a new screen where you can see the timer. In my code everything works fine but the time label  shows on the the new screen one step behind. So when I click the 1st button I see nothing on the new screen, then I click 2nd button and I see the time from the 1st button.

The 1st screen:

```
 import UIKit

 class MeditationController: UIViewController {

    var minutes: String?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       
    }
    @IBAction func minPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToTimer", sender: self)
        minutes = sender.currentTitle!
        
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToTimer" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! TimerViewController
            destinationVC.timer = minutes
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

The 2nd screen:

```
import UIKit

class TimerViewController: UIViewController {
    var timer: String?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
  
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        timerLabel.text = timer

    }
}
```

I am new to programming and I am sure this issue is really easy to solve but I've spent a few hours and I just can't seem to get how to solve this.
Thank you :)

[App View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGYE7.png)

Comment: Put `minutes = sender.currentTitle!` BEFORE `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToTimer", sender: self)`.

Comment: OMG! THis was so easy to fix, thank you so much!!!